# Force user to change password after requesting new password

Tags: php

I have `PHP` project where users can login and request new password if they forget. I also have `init.php` where it directs the user to change password page after logging in with new password.

The code in `INIT.PHP` to redirect the user is as follows:

```
$current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file = end($current_file);

if (logged_in() === true) {

    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    if ($current_file !== 'user.php?p=change_password' && $user_data['password_recover'] == 1) {
        header('Location: user.php?p=change_password&force');
        exit();
    }

}
```

`$current_file` is giving me `user.php` only and this is not enough of course. I have also tried `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which gives me `/user.php?p=change_password` which is fine. But still does not work. I get errors saying `The page isn't redirecting properly`

So to sum up. I need to redirect the user to `user.php?p=change_password&force` if they have requested a new password.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is all done in the database. There is a value which changes from 0 to 1 once they requested a new password

Answer (score 0):

You might be stuck in a redirect loop. Here's what I think happens:

1. You manage to redirect the user to `user.php?p=change_password&force`
2. Once you're on this page, the if statement containing `$current_file !== 'user.php?p=change_password'` is still true
3. Hence, you're trying to redirect the user to the same page that s/he is already on, causing a redirection error

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$current_url = end($current_url);

if (logged_in() === true) {

    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    if ($current_url !== 'user.php?p=change_password' && $user_data['password_recover'] == 1) {
        header('Location: user.php?p=change_password');
        exit();
    }

}
```

This solution worked